# Make Grunt Usemin HTML Task Create New File Instead Of Rewriting

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I have a simple Gruntfile using usemin with a basic default config from a Yeoman generator. I need to be able to create a new html file as opposed to rewriting the html files. This is what I was hoping would work:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: 'index.tpl',
  options: {
    dest: '.',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},

usemin: {
  html: {
    src: 'index.tpl',
    dest: 'index.html'
  }
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible yet. 
The only way actually is to use the grunt-contrib-copy (or such a plugin) to make copy of your index.html file, and then use the copy to be changed by the usemin task.

Here is an exemple of this solution : 
(from mvolkmann's post at https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/176)

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    clean: ['build'],
    copy: {
      html: { // in preparation for usemin
        files: [
          {src: 'index.html', dest: 'build/'}
        ]
      }
    }, 
    uglify: {
      all: {
        files: {
          'build/output.min.js': ['lib/angular.min.js', 'scripts/*.js']
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {dest: 'build'}
    },
    usemin: {
      html: 'build/index.html', // must have this
      //css: '*.css',
      options: {
        dirs: ['lib', 'scripts']
      }
    },
  });

  var tasks = [
    'grunt-contrib-clean',
    'grunt-contrib-copy',
    'grunt-contrib-cssmin',
    'grunt-contrib-uglify',
    'grunt-usemin'
  ];
  tasks.forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.registerTask('min', ['copy', 'useminPrepare', 'uglify', 'usemin']);
};
```